# Pullback of the identity is 'basically' the identity?

Tags: category-theory, pullback

I encountered the titular statement in a discussion on subobject classifiers (in particular: in the proof that the domain of such a subobject classifier is terminal).

However, I think his 'basically' does a little too much heavy lifting here. Consider a category with pullbacks.

Consider the diagram $A \xrightarrow{m} T \xleftarrow{\text{id}_T} T$.   Then it has some pullback $A \xleftarrow{g} A \times_T T \xrightarrow{f} T$.

Is it really true that $g$ is somehow the identity...? I mean, its source and target prevent that already. After a lot of fiddling around with the universal property of pullbacks (choosing arbitrary objects and maps to $A$ and $T$, of specific ones meeting the pullback requirement), I have not come up with a satisfying answer.

So what's going on here? Is $g$ *'basically'* the identity in the sense that precomposing with the unique map $h : A \to A \times_T T$ yields it? i.e., is $g$ the right-inverse to the unique map provided by the universal property of the pullback?

Comment: You are correct in that the map  $g\colon A\times_T T \to A$ is an isomorphism, but does not need to be the identity. But if you replace $g$ by $id_T$ and $f$ by $m$, you will also have a pullback diagram. In fact you can obtain it, by pulling back the original $g$ by $id_T$. 
So $(id_T,g^{-1})\colon id_T \to g$ is an isomorphism in the arrow category.

Comment: Ooh wow, thanks! That clears it up!

Comment: Note that notation like $A ×_T T$ may not mean some particular, systematic formula for pullbacks that entails that it is not the same thing as $A$. In general it refers to _some_ way of mapping cospans to pullbacks in a category with (all) pullbacks, and that mapping _could_ take this particular cospan to $A$ as the (apex of the) pullback. Further, it is a general categorical principle that the differences between that mapping and a more systematic one don't matter, because they are uniquely isomorphic. That is what underlies the "basically."